# Finding a minimum variance unbiased (linear) estimator

Tags: probability, estimation, unbiased-estimator, umvue

Here is a basic question that perhaps has a simple answer, but one that I was not able to find by quickly scanning the literature.

Suppose that I have a collection of $n$ unopened boxes. Each box $i$ contains either a red ball or a blue ball: write $c_i = 1$ if box $i$ contains a red ball, and $c_i = 0$ otherwise. Moreover, each box $i$ has a probability $p_i > 0$ written on it. If I attempt to open box $i$, then with probability $p_i$ I will succeed and observe whether $c_i = 1$ or $c_i = 0$. With probability $1-p_i$ I will fail, and will not learn $c_i$. I can only try once -- if the box does not open, I never learn $c_i$. The parameters for each box $(c_i, p_i)$ are drawn i.i.d from an uknown distribution $\mathcal{D}$. I wish to produce an unbiased estimate of the expected fraction of red balls:$$C \equiv E_{(c_i, p_i) \sim \mathcal{D}}[ c_i]$$ Note that while the marginal distribution on the $c_i$ is Bernoulli, I make no assumptions about how the $p_i$ are distributed -- they could be correlated with the $c_i$ in some arbitrary way.

An obvious first attempt at finding an unbiased estimator is to attempt to open each box, and set $d_i = \frac{c_i}{p_i}$ if the box opens, and $d_i = 0$ otherwise. Then take as my estimate: 
$$S \equiv \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nd_i$$
Since $E[d_i] = C$ for each $i$, this is an unbiased estimator. Can I argue that it is the minimum variance unbiased estimator?

If I was literally sampling the values $d_i$, then I could at least say that $S$ was the minimum variance *linear* unbiased estimator, since each $d_i$ is sampled i.i.d and I am estimating the sample mean. But can I say anything about $S$ given that I am actually sampling $(c_i, p_i)$? Is there a literature on this sort of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your setup is analogous to sampling from a finite population (the $c_i$) without replacement, with a fixed probability $p_i$ of selecting each member of the population for the sample.  Successfully opening the $i^{th}$ box corresponds to selecting the corresponding $c_i$ for inclusion in the sample.

The estimator you describe is a Horvitz-Thompson estimator, which is the *only* unbiased estimator in the class of estimators $\hat{S} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \beta_i c_i$, where $\beta_i$ is a weight to be used whenever $c_i$ is selected for the sample.  Thus, within that class of estimators, it is also the optimal unbiased estimator regardless of the criterion for optimality.

It has been shown ([Ramakrishnan](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-1/issue-3/An-Alternative-Proof-of-the-Admissibility-of-the-Horvitz-Thompson/10.1214/aos/1176342427.full)) that the H-T estimator is admissible in the class of all unbiased estimators of a finite population total.  (Note the link is not to the original paper by Godambe and Joshi, which I can't seem to find online.)

For a review of the Horvitz-Thompson estimator and its properties, see [Rao](http://www.isas.org.in/jisas/login).

Comment: My script tried to fix the broken link but the new one isn't right. Would https://books.google.nl/books?id=f8NY6M-5EEwC be a suitable alternative?

Comment: Yes it would, thanks!  And that'll remind me to put a full(er) cite in with the link.